# Can you use a switch statement with a list of enums in java 6?

Tags: java, enums, command-line-arguments

I know you can have something like

```
public enum letters{
                    A, B, C, D
                   }
```

then have something like with each letter having its own class with a method

```
switch(letters)
case A:
      A.methodA();
      break;
case B:
        B.methodB();
      break;
case C:
        C.methodC();
      break;
case D:
       D.methodD();
      break;
default:
      System.out.println("Learn the alphabet");
```

but can you have something like

```
switch(listOfLetterEnums)
 ...
```

In my program I turn command line enum arguments into a list and I need to know how to run each of the enums' method from that list whether it be a switch statement or something else.

I should add when I try it I get an error saying "cannot convert List. Only convertible int values or enum variables" would converting to a list of enums work if the above is possib

Comment: What you need is a loop. Switch does not loop.

Comment: What does your compiler say?

Comment: Enclose switch statement inside a for loop.

Comment: Simply said: you can't switch on lists in java.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? The short answer is *no*. The long answer is to iterate your list.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to put a for loop around the switch statement to parse each element of the list separately. If the list is an [Iterable](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/implementing-iterable.html) then it should look something like this:

```
for (letterEnum : listOfLetterEnums) {
    switch(letterEnum) {
        ...
    }
}
```

For this to work, your list will need to implement the Iterator interface or extend a class which implements it. In this case you probably want to extend [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

If the list is an array you can just parse each element of the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfLetterEnums.length; i++) {
    switch(listOfLetterEnums[i]) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want to try the top one of your suggestion but technically right now I have a list of strings and I need to convert them into a list of enums. Is there an easy way to do this

Comment: If you have your list implement the java.util.List Interface (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) then this will implement the Iterable Interface for you, allowing you to iterate over the list like in the first solution.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use one of the classes listed in the previous link which will implement the List (and as a result the Iterator) interface for you. ArrayList (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is probably what you want in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    private enum Foo {
        ABC, DEF;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Foo> myfoos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        myfoos.add(Foo.ABC);
        for(Foo i:myfoos)
        switch (i) {
        case ABC:
            System.out.println("do abc");
            break;
        case DEF:
            System.out.println("do def");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the list, and switch based on the value.

```
letters[] listOfLetterEnums = { letters.A, letters.B, letters.C, letters.D };
for(letter let : listOfLetterEnums)
{
    switch(let)
    {
    case A:
        A.methodA();
        break;
    case B:
        B.methodB();
        break;
    case C:
        C.methodC();
        break;
    case D:
        D.methodD();
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Learn the alphabet");
    }
}
```